# Azure API Management - Why is Host header required for requests?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network

I have set up a simple API in API Management.  It is an internal API, connected to a VNet.

I don't have DNS set up for it, so I am testing it via an internal IP address.

The request looks like this:

```
GET http://10.x.x.x/query?id=3
```

If I just send the request without additional headers, I receive a 503 error.

If I add a Host header with the domain name of the API, like this:

```
GET http://10.x.x.x/query?id=3
Host: apixxxxx.azure-api.net
```

Then it works and I receive a 200.

Why is this happening and how can I disable the required Host header?

Or how can I make a successful request from a system that is going to use its own Host header?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the internal virtual network mode, all the service endpoints are only visible within a virtual network that you control access to. It also contains the requests. The private IP address only can access inside the virtual network. And the APIM is accessible with the Domain name, and you can route the requests to the backend in the Internal mode by configuring the route rules. Take a look at the [DNS configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet#apim-dns-configuration). So you need to set the host with the APIM domain name to make it accessible.

Comment: Yes, I know if I set up DNS the problem will be solved.  I was trying to do it without setting up DNS, but it looks like that is not an option.

Comment: @Errator Yes, it would not be accessible when you use the Internal network without configuring the DNS. And if it works for you please accept it as the answer.